# get datetime resultset from mysql google app maker

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-app-maker

Good morning to all;
I am trying get DateTime field value from mysql with the next sentence in Google App Maker server Script:

```
calcRecord.fct_f_FechaRecepcion=results.getDate('dt_Alta');
```

But returns null without exceptions in console.log
I need to get some dates from mysql and I does not know how to do it.
Can any help  me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountred a possible solution after cast the dateTime field in MySql:

```
Select..... cast(******.dt_Alta as char) As dt_Alta from .....
```

My dateFormat pattern is 2019-12-05 00:00:00 . The result:

```
if (results.getString(8)!==null){
    var str,str1='';
    var t,h=[];
    var fecha= new Date();
    str=results.getString(8);
    str1=str.split(" ");
    t= str1[0].split("-");
    h=str1[1].split(":");
    fecha= new Date(t[0],t[1]-1,t[2],h[0],h[1],h[2]);
    calcRecord.fct_f_FechaRecepcion=fecha;
  }
```

Index of 't' and 'h' is the format for your Date. getString(8) is the column dt_Alta index.
Regards